# How do I get fetch and store the ID of the row I'm clicking the button on?

Tags: php, laravel, store

To briefly explain my title: I've a table where I'm printing all the users and their information. I've a **Create Schedule** button on each row. When I click the Create Schedule button, I go to a page where I'll fill out a 7-day weekly schedule of THAT user and then save it. When I save it, I want all the data I just filled out, to save in a separate database table called 'schedules' where I also have a column called 'user_id', which is the ID of the user I'm adding the schedule of. Now, I've achieved most of it except the part where I save the ID of the user whose schedule I'm creating, in the Schedules DB table. Here's my create() & store() functions:

**ScheduleController** (Resource Controller):

```
public function create(User $user) {
    $user_id = User::all()->where('id',"=",$user->id);
    return view('createschedule',compact('user_id'));
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request, Schedule $schedule, User $user) {

    $schedule->user_id =  User::all()->where('id',"=",$user->id);
    $schedule->mon1 = $request->input('mon1');
    $schedule->mon2 = $request->input('mon2');
    $schedule->mon3 = $request->input('mon3');
    $schedule->mon4 = $request->input('mon4');
    $schedule->mon5 = $request->input('mon5');
    $schedule->mon6 = $request->input('mon6');
    $schedule->mon7 = $request->input('mon7');

    $schedule->save();
    return redirect()->route('dashboard.index');
}
```

**CreateSchedule.blade.php** (The view with the Schedule Form):

```
{!! Form::open(array('route'=>'schedule.store')) !!}
                    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" border="2" cellspacing="3" align="center">
                            <tr>
                             <td align="center">
                             <td>8:30-9:30
                             <td>9:30-10:30
                             <td>10:3-11:30
                             <td>11:30-12:30
                             <td>12:30-2:00
                             <td>2:00-3:00
                             <td>3:00-4:00
                             <td>4:00-5:00
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                             <td align="center">MONDAY
                             <td align="center">{!! Form::select('mon1', [
                                    'Math' => 'Math',
                                    'English' => 'English',
                                    'Physics' => 'Physics',
                                    'Computer' => 'Computer',],null, ['class'=>'custom-select','placeholder' => 'Subject']); !!}
                             <td align="center">{!! Form::select('mon2', [
                                    'Math' => 'Math',
                                    'English' => 'English',
                                    'Physics' => 'Physics',
                                    'Computer' => 'Computer',],null, ['class'=>'custom-select','placeholder' => 'Subject']); !!}<br>
                             <td align="center">{!! Form::select('mon3', [
                                    'Math' => 'Math',
                                    'English' => 'English',
                                    'Physics' => 'Physics',
                                    'Computer' => 'Computer',],null, ['class'=>'custom-select','placeholder' => 'Subject']); !!}<br>
                             <td align="center">{!! Form::select('mon4', [
                                    'Math' => 'Math',
                                    'English' => 'English',
                                    'Physics' => 'Physics',
                                    'Computer' => 'Computer',],null, ['class'=>'custom-select','placeholder' => 'Subject']); !!}<br>
                             <td rowspan="6"align="center">L<br><br>U<br><br>N<br><br>C<br><br>H
                             <td align="center">{!! Form::select('mon5', [
                                    'Math' => 'Math',
                                    'English' => 'English',
                                    'Physics' => 'Physics',
                                    'Computer' => 'Computer',],null, ['class'=>'custom-select','placeholder' => 'Subject']); !!}<br>
                             <td align="center">{!! Form::select('mon6', [
                                    'Math' => 'Math',
                                    'English' => 'English',
                                    'Physics' => 'Physics',
                                    'Computer' => 'Computer',],null, ['class'=>'custom-select','placeholder' => 'Subject']); !!}<br>
                             <td align="center">{!! Form::select('mon7', [
                                    'Math' => 'Math',
                                    'English' => 'English',
                                    'Physics' => 'Physics',
                                    'Computer' => 'Computer',],null, ['class'=>'custom-select','placeholder' => 'Subject']); !!}
                            </tr>

</table>
{!! Form::submit('Create',['type'=>'submit','class'=>'btn btn-success btn-block']) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

**Dashboard View** (Where I'm printing all users and passing their respective IDs to the Add Schedule button):

```
<table id="myTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                        <thead>
                    <tr>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>Username</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Roll Number</th>
                    <th>Class</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        @foreach($users as $user)
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ $user->fname }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $user->lname }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $user->name }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $user->email }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $user->rollno }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $user->class }}</td>
                        <td class="btn-group">
                                {{ link_to_route('schedule.create','Create Schedule',[$user->id],['style'=>'border-radius: 0px;','class'=> 'btn btn-success btn-sm']) }}
                                </td>
                    </tr>
                        @endforeach
                        </tbody>
                </table>
```

**Now**, when I press create, the data does go to the desired database table but the user_id is saved as **[ ]**, which I'm guessing means empty. So kindly, if someone can navigate me through what I'm doing wrong here and how I could save the ID of the user I'm creating the schedule for, I'll be thankful.

Comment: I'm not sue but can you change User::all()->where('id',"=",$user->id); to User::where('id',"=",$user->id); ?

Comment: oh just 2 things popped into my mind: 1 after where you should also add ->get()
2 why everytime you get user->where id = user id rather that find()? and then you would just use user->id

I should say I'm not sure i'm correct or not it just the things that popped into my mind and worth trying

Comment: When I'm doing `$user_id = User::where('id',"=",$user->id)->get();
        dd($user_id);` in create() function, I'm getting: `Collection {#301 ▼
  #items: []
}`

Comment: oh so you see there is something wrong in this line. all the other things are correct.
where do you get this $user from?   if you dd($user) what would you get

Comment: $user contains data of all my registered users, dd'ing it gives me data of all my users. But all I want from $user is the ID of the user I'm adding schedule of. That's what I'm trying to save. The $user->id on my 'Create Schedule' button works perfectly as the URL of the schedule page is create/{$user->id} but only using $user->id doesn't work in store/create.

Comment: Hi, so sorry mate I was a little bit busy, I'm sure you have solved the issue by now, but I just wanted to make it clear for myself as well so if in future i had a similar situation I would be able to solve it :) , so based on what you said user is all your registered users not just one but all? right, then $user->id should not work because it's a collection not a single user, you should first get one user, am i right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass the user ID in the store route.

```
 Form::open(array('route' => array('route.store', 'id' => $user_id)))
```

And then in the controller, you can retrieve id.

```
 public function create(Request $request) {
      If($request->id){
          $user_id = User::where('id', "=", $request->id)->select ('id')->first();
          return view('createschedule',compact('user_id'));
     }
 }


public function store(Request $request, Schedule $schedule){
    $schedule->user_id = $request->id;
}
```

Edit view file: 
Make sure `$user->id` exist.

```
<td class="btn-group">
     {{ link_to_route('schedule.create','Create Schedule',['id' => $user->id],['style'=>'border-radius: 0px;','class'=> 'btn btn-success btn-sm']) }}
</td>
```

Comment: `Undefined variable: user_id (View: \createschedule.blade.php)`

This is what I get when I put $user_id (an undefined variable at that point) in my route

Comment: This just shows me a blank page, mainly because $user->id gives me an error of "Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance" or it's "null"..

Comment: `Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\ScheduleController::create(), 0 passed and exactly 1 expected` 

This is what I get everytime I try to pass $id in create() or store()

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't use `$schedule->user_id =  $user_id;` in the code since it was giving argument errors but excluding it and using rest of the code worked for me! Again, thanks for devoting your time to solve this issue!

Comment: @VenoM Sorry actually I had written two store method in the answer. The second one is right, `$schedule->user_id = $request->id;`